# How can I retrieve the exception message from Request.CreateErrorResponse?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have this code in my controller:

```
return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, new Exception("Your cat is too small"));
```

In my calling code, I want to retrieve the Exception or at least the error. I wrote this code:

```
ObjectContent objContent = response.Content as ObjectContent;
```

The objContent is of type `HttpError`, so I pulled that out:

```
HttpError error = objContent.Value as HttpError;
```

But `error` seems to be a Dictionary with one value, key: Message, ValueL "An error has occurred"

I can't see any sign of the exception.

```
Assert.AreEqual("Your cat is too small", error["Message"]);
```

The assertion fails.

Comment: `HttpError` has properties `ExceptionMessage` and `InnerException`. Are those populated?

Comment: Afraid not, both are `null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used your code and reproduced the problem.

I wasn't able to step in to the .NET code to see why the `Exception` was being swallowed, so I had a look at the [HttpRequestMessageExtensions source on GitHub](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/HttpRequestMessageExtensions.cs) and found that it passes the the `Exception` to a new `HttpError` object that is created from configuration (line 459).

I took the .NET code and doctored up the following to see what would happen.

```
private static HttpResponseMessage Test()
{
    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage();

    return Test2(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, new Exception("Your cat is adequately sized."));
}

public static HttpResponseMessage Test2(HttpStatusCode statusCode, Exception exception)
{
    return Test2(statusCode, includeErrorDetail => new HttpError(exception, includeErrorDetail));
}

private static HttpResponseMessage Test2(HttpStatusCode statusCode, Func< bool, HttpError > errorCreator)
{
    HttpError r = errorCreator(false);
    return null;    
}
```

When I inspect the value of `r`, I can't see the `Exception`. If I change the value of the `bool` passed to `errorCreator` above to `true`. I can see much more detail when inspecting `r`.

I'm not great with the `Web` or `Http` namespaces, so you'll have to figure out how to pass true to that `HttpError` from the source on GH.

It doesn't directly answer the question, but hopefully it points you in the right direction.

Comment: Many thanks. I tried some overloads then gave up and just used `return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, new Exception(myMessage));`. That deserialises into an Exception. I guess it was overlooked in development.

Comment: That's really odd. I didn't know it deserialized, but glad you found a workable solution.