# How to read CreateErrorResponse custom message in exception

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api

I can't see `CreateErrorResponse` message in exception. I am passing message "Invalid Parameters" to `ThrowResponseException` method but i can't read it in exception.

`e.Response.RequestMessage` gives default detail message but i only need to read "Invalid Parameters".

```cs
try
{
  If (!ValidString)
  { ThrowResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Invalid Parameters");}
}
catch (HttpResponseException e)
{
    msg = " Status Code: " + e.Response.StatusCode.ToString();
}

private void ThrowResponseException(HttpStatusCode statusCode, string message)
{
    var errorResponse = Request.CreateErrorResponse(statusCode,message);
    throw new HttpResponseException(errorResponse);
}
```

Comment: Looks like its working if i remove the catch block.I will have to change code to  HttpResponseMessage message = new HttpResponseMessage(statusCode);
            message.Content = new StringContent(msg);
            throw new HttpResponseException(message);

Answer (score 0):

I found something similar where they wrap the message in a new exception and pass that exception into the create response. Then they can pull out the text of the error message.
[How can I retrieve the exception message from Request.CreateErrorResponse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38746726/how-can-i-retrieve-the-exception-message-from-request-createerrorresponse)

```
return Request.CreateResponse(statusCode, new Exception(message));
```